# How to change the move / calorie Activity goal on an Apple Watch?

Tags: apple-watch, activity.app, apple-watch.app

I've recently set up a new Apple Watch; during the setup process I selected the "most active" setting (*Very Active*, I think).

Now that I've seen the daily targets in the Activity app, I realise that the move/caloria goal (red ring) is too high.

Can I change that?

I've looked in a bunch of places, including the general *Settings*, *Health* settings, and *Activity* settings (all in the *Watch* app on the iPhone) - and the *Activity* app on the iPhone. But no luck.

Additionally, can the three goals be changed independently?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The option is hidden behind a long/hard press - so not easily discoverable:

- Tap on the Activity app from your Apple Watch's Home screen.
- Swipe left until you see the Move ring.
- Press firmly on the screen.
- Tap on Change Move Goal.
- Adjust your move goal to whatever you'd like and tap Update.

Source: [How to set a calorie goal with Activity for Apple Watch](http://www.imore.com/how-set-calorie-goal-activity-apple-watch)

The calorie goal is the only configurable goal.

Comment: Actually, it turns out you can do the firm press on any of the screens in the Activity app, not just the one showing the Move ring. Cheers.